Static IP on Ubuntu Server
I'm trying to setup a static IP on Ubuntu Server, but I’m not able to set 192.168.16.244 as you can see.
Do you have any advice?


In short, you don't have to enter a subnet mask, rather a subnet expressed in CIDR notation, which is the network followed by the number of set bits in the mask. So in your case it should be : 192.168.16.0/23

255.255.254.0 is equal to /23, so you don't need to add the /23 after the subnet.
